# Swift different images for Annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkpointannotation

I managed to get a custom icon for a annotation pin in Swift, but now I am still stuck using 2 different images for different annotations. Right now a button adds a annotation to the map.  There should be another button that also adds a annotation but with another icon.

Is there a way to use the reuseId for this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var Map: MKMapView!

@IBAction func btpressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    var lat:CLLocationDegrees = 40.748708
    var long:CLLocationDegrees = -73.985643
    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    var longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)
    var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
    var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)


    var information = MKPointAnnotation()
    information.coordinate = location
    information.title = "Test Title!"
    information.subtitle = "Subtitle"

    Map.addAnnotation(information)
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if !(annotation is MKPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView.image = UIImage(named:"1.png")
        anView.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        anView.annotation = annotation
    }

    return anView
}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method, set the `image` based on which `annotation` the method is being called for.

Be sure to do this *after* the view is dequeued or created (and not only in the `if anView == nil` part).  Otherwise, annotations that use a dequeued view will show the image of the annotation that used the view previously.

With the basic `MKPointAnnotation`, one crude way to tell annotations apart is by their `title` but that's not very flexible.

A better approach is to use a custom annotation class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol (an easy way to do that is to subclass `MKPointAnnotation`) and add whatever properties are needed to help implement the custom logic.

In the custom class, add a property, say `imageName`, which you can use to customize the image based on the annotation.

This example subclasses `MKPointAnnotation`:

```
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var imageName: String!
}
```

Create annotations of type `CustomPointAnnotation` and set their `imageName`:

```
var info1 = CustomPointAnnotation()
info1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42, -84)
info1.title = "Info1"
info1.subtitle = "Subtitle"
info1.imageName = "1.png"

var info2 = CustomPointAnnotation()
info2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32, -95)
info2.title = "Info2"
info2.subtitle = "Subtitle"
info2.imageName = "2.png"
```

In `viewForAnnotation`, use the `imageName` property to set the view's `image`:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        anView.annotation = annotation
    }

    //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
    //the view is dequeued or created...

    let cpa = annotation as CustomPointAnnotation
    anView.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)

    return anView
}
```

Comment: Simple and straightforward +1

Comment: Just a note that you need to implement the protocol 'MKMapViewDelegate' and configure your controller to be your delegate (either in the storyboard or manually in the code) for the `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! ` method to work.  This tripped me up for a bit.

Comment: the best answer i found for this question. +1 for the order and the simplicity of the answer

Comment: @Anna my pin points are not displaying on the map. only callout is there. whats wrong

Comment: Hi @Anna, My all points are not covered in my UImapview, it is going out of bounds... What should be the case?

Comment: @Anna how would I do this to display a different callout view for each of the 3 annotation types I have? Thanks

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value . I'm getting this error at `let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation `

Comment: i am use this but it is also show default pin image.

Answer (score 13):

iOS Swift Code With Help of Anna and Fabian Boulegue:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.mapView.delegate = self

        var info1 = CustomPointAnnotation()
        info1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.889281, 75.836042)
        info1.title = "Info1"
        info1.subtitle = "Subtitle"
        info1.imageName = "flag.png"

        var info2 = CustomPointAnnotation()
        info2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.862280, 75.815098)
        info2.title = "Info2"
        info2.subtitle = "Subtitle"
        info2.imageName = "flag.png"

        mapView.addAnnotation(info1)
        mapView.addAnnotation(info2)
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        println("delegate called")

        if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "test"

        var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
        if anView == nil {
            anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            anView.canShowCallout = true
        }
        else {
            anView.annotation = annotation
        }

        //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
        //the view is dequeued or created...

        let cpa = annotation as CustomPointAnnotation
        anView.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)

        return anView
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var imageName: String!
}
```

Comment: for Swift 3 I had to change to use: `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {`

Comment: Need to downcast the annotation to CustomPointAnnotation. Change it to `let pickupCustomAnno = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation`

Comment: would that be bad to leave the reuseId as "test" ? what would that bring ?