# Add extra property to MKPointAnnotation in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit, subclass

I am looking to add a UIImage to a MKPointAnnottion.

NOT TO BE SHOWN IN THE CALLOUT, but to be shown on a separate page when the callout is clicked.

I think it would be something like a subclass but I am not to sure how to do that.

Any guidance/solution would be great

Thanks

Ben

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631410/swift-different-images-for-annotation for one approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you want to subclass `MKPointAnnotation` to add a generic property. In your case, a `UIImage`.