# custom MKAnnotationView swift: func mapView does nothing

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am trying to set an image instead of a pin on a map using MapKit. I know I have to set a custom `MKAnnotationView`. Therefore I should implement the following lines:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        anView.annotation = annotation
    }

    //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
    //the view is dequeued or created...

    let cpa = annotation as CustomPointAnnotation
    anView.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)

    return anView
}
```

But it is simply not working in my code. I copy/pasted all the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631410/swift-different-images-for-annotation), adding an image called 1.png to my supporting file. But the map displays a red pin instead of the 1.png image.

It looks like the whole mapView function is useless. Do I have to call it in viewDidLoad? How am I supposed to make it being used? Also, what is the reuseId for? Where should I call it?

Thank you for your answers and happy new year.

Comment: Did you set the `delegate` of the `MKMapView` to `self` in your view controller?

Comment: (Or set the `delegate` to be the view controller when you designed this scene in Interface Builder?)

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I've spend the whole year looking for the answer. The picture finally appeared. It is now gigantic but I'll see if I can edit the frame. If not I'll edit the picture itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that the MKMapView's delegate is properly linked to the ViewController that implements that method.

You could do this in the "viewWillAppear" method like this: mapView.delegate = self;

Or in the InterfaceBuilder:
- Be sure that your MapKit View is selected
- Go to the "Connections Inspector"
- In the "Outlets" section, Drag and drop the "delegate" attribute to the ViewController that implements the delegate method