# How to add custom images to annotations in Mapview Swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift3, mkmapview, mkannotation

```
 var lat:CLLocationDegrees = 40.748708
    var long:CLLocationDegrees = -73.985643
    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    var longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)
    var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
    var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)


    var information = MKPointAnnotation()
    information.coordinate = location
    information.title = "Test Title!"
    information.subtitle = "Subtitle"



    mapView.addAnnotation(information)
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {


    if !(annotation is MKPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView?.image = UIImage(named:"annotation")
        anView?.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        anView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return anView
}
```

I need to load custom image for the annotation in Mapview. I have an image named "Annotation" and I am trying to call it in viewfor annotation method. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This may be help full for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631410/swift-different-images-for-annotation

Comment: @Miteshjadav I have used the same method. But still the image is not changing. Please help

Answer (score 7):

Here is the answer:

Swift 4:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    // Don't want to show a custom image if the annotation is the user's location.
    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
        return nil
    }

    // Better to make this class property
    let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
    if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    else {
        let av = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        av.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        annotationView = av
    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView {
        // Configure your annotation view here
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Swift 3:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    // Don't want to show a custom image if the annotation is the user's location.
    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
        return nil
    }

    // Better to make this class property
    let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
    if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView {
        // Configure your annotation view here
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Swift 2.2:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    // Don't want to show a custom image if the annotation is the user's location.
    guard !annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation) else {
        return nil
    }

    let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
    if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(annotationIdentifier) {
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    else {
        let av = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        av.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
        annotationView = av
    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView {
        // Configure your annotation view here
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: Still the image is not loading.

Comment: @Rakesh which version of swift are you using? and also can you please check the image exits in your image asset or not. Because I've also check with above code it is showing me my image

Comment: I am using swift3. My image exist in the asset.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.0

```
var coordinates: [[Double]]!
var addresses:[String]!
```

In viewDidload() add following code to add annotations to MapvView.

```
    coordinates = [[28.4344,72.5401],[28.85196,72.3944],[28.15376,72.1953]]// Latitude,Longitude
    addresses = ["Address1","Address2","Address3"]
    self.mapView.delegate = self // set MapView delegate to self
    for i in 0...2 {
        let coordinate = coordinates[i]
        let point = CustomAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate[0] , longitude: coordinate[1] )) // CustomAnnotation is class and pass the required param
        point.address = addresses[i] // passing only address to pin, you can add multiple properties according to need
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(point)
    }
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.856614, longitude: 72.3522219), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Add new class having name CustomAnnotation inherited from MKAnnotation for our custom annotation

```
import MapKit
class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var address: String!
    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

Add one more class having name AnnotationView inherited from MKAnnotationView. I am showing custom callout so it it is required to to override the overridefuncpoint() method to receive touch in custom callout view.

```
import MapKit
class AnnotationView: MKAnnotationView
{
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        if (hitView != nil)
        {
            self.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: self)
        }
        return hitView
    }
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let rect = self.bounds;
        var isInside: Bool = rect.contains(point);
        if(!isInside)
        {
            for view in self.subviews
            {
                isInside = view.frame.contains(point);
                if isInside
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return isInside;
    }
}
```

Now implement viewForannotation MapView delegate as follow

```
    extension YourViewC: MKMapViewDelegate {

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            if annotation is MKUserLocation
            {
                return nil
            }
            var annotationView = self.mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "CustomPin")
            if annotationView == nil{
                annotationView = AnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "CustomPin")
                annotationView?.canShowCallout = false
            }else{
                annotationView?.annotation = annotation
            }
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "bluecircle") // Pass name of your custom image
            return annotationView
        }
     func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
                 didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){ 
        let annotation = view.annotation as? CustomAnnotation
       print(annotation?.address) // get info you passed on pin

      // write code here to add custom view on tapped annotion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is using custom class to store annotations.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class Annotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
var title: String?
var subtitle: String?

var strTitle = ""
var strImgUrl = ""
var strDescr = ""


init(coordinates location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title1: String, description: String, imgURL: String) {
    super.init()

    coordinate = location
    title = title1
    subtitle = description
    strTitle = title1
    strImgUrl = imgURL
    strDescr = description
}
}
```

Now use this class to store annotation and populate your pins.

```
//  MapViewController.swift
let myAnnotation1: Annotation = Annotation.init(coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 30.733051, longitude: 76.763042), title1: "The Mayflower Renaissance Hotel", description: "The Histroic hotel has been the site of saveral dramatic locations.", imgURL: "custom.jpg")
    self.uvMApView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation1)

  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
   if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }
    // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
    let AnnotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

    let myAnnotation1 = (annotation as! Annotation)

    let pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: AnnotationIdentifier)
    pinView.canShowCallout = true
    pinView.image = UIImage(named: myAnnotation1. strImgUrl)!
    return pinView

   }
```

Comment: Still the images is not loading @Ankit Saini

Comment: The image you are trying to load is in you app bundle or you are loading it from some URL?. If this is the server image then you have to replace { pinView.image = UIImage(named: myAnnotation1. strImgUrl)! }.

Comment: It's in my Project.

Answer (score 1):

After spending lot of time, i came up with a simple code.
1. Don't use .pdf images, use only .png images with three different sizes such as 1x, 2x, 3x. Below is my sample code.

```
@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapViewSetup()
}

func mapViewSetup(){
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        // For use in foreground
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.mapType = .standard
        mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
        mapView.isScrollEnabled = true
        mapView.showsUserLocation = false

        if let coor = mapView.userLocation.location?.coordinate{
            mapView.setCenter(coor, animated: true)
        }
    }

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard

        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locValue, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = locValue
        annotation.title = "Arshad"
        annotation.subtitle = "BrightSword Technologies Pvt Ltd"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        //centerMap(locValue)
    }

private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customannotation")
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "icon_location_pin")
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true

        return annotationView
    }
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
    let reuseId = "pin"
    var your_pin = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    let your_image = UIImage (named: "your_image")

    pinView?.image = your_image
    pinView?.canShowCallout = true
```

I think it is the more easily answer.